# Is there any difference between "it's dead to me" and "it's dead for me?"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, differences

I read [iTunes Is Dead to Me](http://gizmodo.com/itunes-an-obituary-1719479490) and was curious if there is any difference between saying "iTunes is dead *to* me" and "iTunes is dead *for* me?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> "Dead to me" is an idiom.  It's an extreme rejection on the order of,
>   "You're no son of mine".
>
> "Dead for me" is not idiomatic and could be easily taken to mean you
>   can't get iTunes to work.

So while a literal reading might see them as the same, in common usage they aren't.

Comment: @Misti - perhaps I'm an idiot, but why'd you quotify the first part of the answer? Is it actually quoted from somewhere?

Answer (score -2):

Dead for me means, I don't like or love someone anymore. I've literally stopped any relationship with them.

Dead to you is like assuming someone whom you know doesn't exist yet he is still alive. You don't want to talk to him/her, you don't want to text, call, chat or communicate with them in anyway because they might have disappointed you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Have you got some evidence about what "dead for me" means? Because it doesn't seem to have a distinct meaning based on web searches, dictionaries, and other sources. It's just an adjective and a prepositional phrase. The most common meaning I find is "dead" as in broken or offline, for me at least.